# Stripping ^M from output of cygwin programs

Tags: windows, cygwin, ocaml, newline

I recently installed cygwin-x86_64, and gtk from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.24/gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.zip and ocaml from http://protz.github.io/ocaml-installer/.  Whenever I run a command from a binary that got "precompiled for cygwin" (such as ocaml or gtk), it appends a ^M to the end of the output.  For example,

```
$ ocamlc -where > foo; cat -v foo
D:/OCaml/lib^M
```

How do I fix this problem?

**Update:** If I copy the binary to `~/` (or some other cygwin path), then I don't get the `^M` output.  It only happens when the binary is on an MS DOS location.  Is there a way to fix this without moving my binaries?

Running `mount` gives

`$ mount
D:/cygwin64/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
D:/cygwin64/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
D:/cygwin64 on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /cygdrive/d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
E: on /cygdrive/e type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
Y: on /cygdrive/y type afs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
Z: on /cygdrive/z type afs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)`

Answer (score 0):

The ^M is the `Carriage Return`, which is used in Windows, but not in Unix like system. Use sed, tr or your favorite tool to remove the CR from file. 
If you are in windows command line, then

```
tr -d '\r'  < foo.txt > bar.txt
sed -e 's/\r//g' foo.txt > bar.txt
```

If you are using terminal that enabled vi-mode, then

```
tr -d '^M'  < foo.txt > bar.txt
sed -e 's/^M//g' foo.txt > bar.txt
```

The ^M can be input by key Ctrl + M

Comment: I'd rather not have to go edit all of the `./configure` files and all of the Makefiles of every bit of software I want to build to strip these carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds wrong to mix cygwin and ocaml-installer by protz. The last one is for native windows (and in that installer cygwin is used only to provide shell). If you want to use ocaml in cygwin (with cygwin gcc compiler and libraries) then you have to install ocaml from cygwin repository (via cygwin-setup.exe). There is a difference between native windows programs and cygwin-compiled programs, and you will hardly succeed in mixing them for development..